# Octave set break point in a class function

Tags: class, debugging, octave, breakpoints

How do I set a break point in an Octave class function when the class is implemented in a single m file?

Octave documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Breakpoints.html
briefly mentions:

```
Breakpoints in class methods are also supported (e.g., dbstop ("@class/method")).
```

However, my classdef file is a single m file directly sitting in my work dir. How do I set a break point in this case? I tried to do it in Octave 4.0.0 GUI, and in command window, use dbstop with various arguments I can imagine. But none worked. In Matlab, it is as simple as a click in the GUI editor.

Comment: I reported it as [Octave bug #46451](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?46451)

Comment: Thank you. Related to this, Octave 4.0.0 cannot set break point for the class in a directory either. I submitted a bug report at [link](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?46468).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it does not work.

You are right, this should be possible, but it does not work due to a bug in Octave. The bug is already reported as [#45404](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45404) on the Octave bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you Toby for the hint. I have tried to make it an "answer":

Answer (score 0):

Use the command keyboard().
This freezes the programm and
gives the user access to the keyboard.
It is working similar to a breakpoint.

Comment: If you think pausing the program is similar to a breakpoint, then you don’t know what a debugger is. Sorry, but this is certainly not similar at all. `keyboard()` doesn’t let you examine the call stack or the values of variables, nor let you step through the program line by line, nor …